# Are there an example of $a^b \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $a,b$ are algebraic irrationals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Similar question:

1. Are there an example of $a^b \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $a,b$ are transcendentals?
2. What if $a$ and $b$ are algebraically independent?

Comment: $e^{\ln 3} = 3$ and both $e , \ln 3$ are known to be transcendental.

Comment: ^they are also algebraically independent(if that means what i think it means, i.e, similar to linear independence)

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a \not= 0,1$ and $b$ irrational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number by the Gelfond-Schneider theorem so the answer to your first question is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gelfond Schneider theorem is for a, b algebraic, a≠0,1,b algebraic irrational, is transcendental. So $$a^b $$ does not belong to Rational and algebraic irrational.